# MSBuild - skip ValidatePublishProfileSettings for referenced projects

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, msbuild

We've got a webapp csproj build which references a number of other DLL's/wcf services. It fails when it tries to build the referenced wcf sevices at the ValidatePublishProfileSettings step. The class assembly references don't hit this step, it just copies the DLL's and moves to the next.

The publish profile is set in the original csproj file, we don't want to set it for each of the referenced wcf services.

Any thoughts on how to skip this publish profile step would be much appreciated.

msbuild 4.0